# Can't access mux params when testing API endpoint with custom handlers

Tags: api, rest, go, testing

I have a custom handler for my API endpoints like this:

```golang
type HTTPError struct {
    Error   error
    Message string
    Code    int
}

type endpointREST func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) *HTTPError

func (fn endpointREST) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if e := fn(w, r); e != nil {
        http.Error(w, e.Message, e.Code)
    }
}
```

my example route look like this:

```golang
func GetShare(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *HTTPError {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    fmt.Println(r.URL)  // http://127.0.0.1:36455/share/5713d228-a042-446d-a5e4-183b19fa832a
    fmt.Println(vars)  // -->> always empty map when testing 
    return nil
}
```

These routes work well (manual, using Postman) after setting them up with

```golang
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
handler := cors.Default().Handler(router)
router.Handle("/share/{id}", endpointREST(GetShare)).Methods("GET")
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":6969", handler))
```

The Problem is, that i can't test the API this way, since `mux.Vars(r)` will always return an empty map in the testing environment.

This is my testing code:

```golang
func TestGetShare(t *testing.T) {
    Reset()
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    ts := httptest.NewServer(router)
    router.Handle("/share/{id}", endpointREST(GetShare)).Methods("GET")
    defer ts.Close()

    t.Run("unauthorized", func(t *testing.T) {
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", ts.URL + "/share/5713d228-a042-446d-a5e4-183b19fa832a", nil)
        res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusUnauthorized, res.StatusCode)
    })
}
```

Comment: Is `httptest.Server` guaranteed to serve from `http://localhost:6969`? Shouldn't you be using [`Server.URL`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server.URL) instead? e.g. `ts.URL + "/share/5713d228-a042-446d-a5e4-183b19fa832a"`. You know, like in the [example](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#example_Server).

Comment: I just though about the same thing. but it doesent seem to fix it. I updates the question a bit

Comment: The updated code uses a "path only" URL as argument to NewRequest, that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Also to make the `httptest.Server` actually useful you need to send the request to the test server with a client, e.g.  `http.DefaultClient.Do`. Invoking `GetShare` directly in the test circumvents the server and renders it pointless.

Comment: Thank you!! i got it to work using `http.DefaultClient.Do`. However i dumped httptest.NewRecorder(), i hope this isn't an issue for testing

Comment: Should be ok when using `httptest.Server`. Here is example code with and without httptest.Server: https://play.golang.org/p/Zb75wQl9T9D

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you tu use the [SetURLVars test helper func](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/d07530f46e1eec4e40346e24af34dcc6750ad39f/test_helpers.go):

```
// SetURLVars sets the URL variables for the given request, to be accessed via
// mux.Vars for testing route behaviour. Arguments are not modified, a shallow
// copy is returned.
//
// This API should only be used for testing purposes; it provides a way to
// inject variables into the request context. Alternatively, URL variables
// can be set by making a route that captures the required variables,
// starting a server and sending the request to that server.
func SetURLVars(r *http.Request, val map[string]string) *http.Request {
    return requestWithVars(r, val)
}
```